# Aligning CAShapeLayer center of my UIView

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

I've been trying to solve this for days, and none of the suggestions solved my problem. I have a `UIView` inside a `UITableView`. I've been trying to draw my `CAShapeLayer` inside my `UIView`, but I just can't get it right.

I need my yellow `CAShapeLayer` to be exactly center within the gray `UIView`.

```
func DrawActivityRect(cell: CalorieDashboardTVCell){
    let rectangle = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.calorieBurnUIView.bounds)

    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    trackLayer.frame = cell.calorieBurnUIView.bounds
    trackLayer.path = rectangle.cgPath
    trackLayer.position = cell.calorieBurnUIView.center
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    cell.calorieBurnUIView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: From where do you call DrawActivityRect?

Comment: In my cellForRow of tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the cell size change after you have set the layer. The easiest place to fix this is in the cell's `layoutSubviews()`. Since your path is using absolute coordinates you need to update both the layer frame and the path.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // You need to keep trackLayer around after you created it
    let rectangle = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.calorieBurnUIView.bounds)
    self.trackLayer.frame = cell.calorieBurnUIView.bounds
    self.trackLayer.path = rectangle.cgPath
    self.trackLayer.position = cell.calorieBurnUIView.center
}
```

Comment: You are right that the cell size changes after I've set the layer. Scrolling away and coming back adds a new CAShapeLayer that has proper measurement. However, your solution doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: Ah, I think you must also update the path. See my updated solution.

Comment: This answer didn't actually solve my problem. However I understand the idea where you are getting.